# WP Plugin Resource URL not accessible

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting, w3-total-cache

I am using Wordpress 3.8.4 with Total Cache (ver 0.9.4) and SyntaxHighlighter Evolved (ver  3.1.10) on my custom hosted wp site hosted at hostgator.

After I added SyntaxHighlighter plugin recently, I found its files are not loading properly when I am viewing site as a regular visitor (logged out), if I logged in as admin, it works fine.

The issue I was able to find was a some query string in URL being added to the plugin files which was added by SyntaxHighlighter plugin. But I have no clue how to fix this. If I check manually after removing query strings from URL it works.

Here is the URL that it is requesting and not loading:

http://domain.com/wp-content/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter3/styles/shCore.css?b3141b?ver=3.0.9

This gives following error:

[image: Error 403]

This one works:
http://domain.com/wp-content/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter3/styles/shCore.css?b3141b

Can anyone point me to right direction, what could be the issue, and how to resolve this?

Comment: It seems like SyntaxHighlighter is adding the ?ver=3.0.9 but without checking for other GET parameters. Two question marks in the URL could cause the not loading problem. did you try searching for the code adding `ver` to the GET parameters?

Comment: Do you mean checking into the plugin code? But which plugin syntaxhighlighter or w3tc?

Comment: SyntaxHighlighter, since that is the plugin causing the problem

Comment: noted. I will check and try to find this. thank you for your hint.

Comment: do you suggest to change into plugin code files if I'm able to find that?

Comment: No, never change plugin files, updating the plugin would overwrite the changes. If you know where the `ver` is added, you/we can probably create a work around.

Comment: Can you advise how? I am looking at its plugin file, but couldn't figure out how to remove it!

Comment: Could you give me the code where you use the URL? I need more information to help with a workaround

Comment: Sure, I posted php file code here.. http://www.codeshare.io/8RHBa I made some changes. Search for Changed and you'll find changes I did.

Comment: The changes I did seems to work but something seems to be broken, changes was on line 228, 1252 and 1293. I also added comments. Pls advise how to do this in clean manner that won't break plugin and ensure easy update.

Comment: That's the plugin code, on line 1252 there's a param missing (second param) `$corecssurl = add_query_arg( '', , $wp_styles->registered['syntaxhighlighter-core']->src );`.

Comment: I have removed that, check the comments above those lines.

Comment: If you want to remove the variable, you have to replace it with '' (empty string) or null, otherwise that line of code will produce an error

Comment: Can you advise the best way to do this in neat way without breaking plugin and ensuring easy update of newer version of plugin. I don't think its good to change into core plugin files!

Comment: Have you updated the plugin and saved the plugin settings? Some people have problems with the plugin after updating. I know a workaround by overwriting the syntaxhighlighter_cssthemeurl filter, but I have to find the definition of that filter first.

Comment: Yes, I have updated plugin and saved the plugin and tested it works good. But as the changes are directly into plugin core files it will create problem while upgrading plugin.